# Pausing and resuming a Workflow (flowchart) hosted by IIS7

Tags: workflow

I have a WCF Workflow Service Application (hosted by IIS7). Within it I have a workflow (a flowchart) which I need to pause, then resume if a condition has been met.

After a lot of reading I understand that pausing and resuming is achieved by using a bookmark (which I have in a code activity) and once the path of execution hits the bookmark, the workflow is unloaded.

I cannot find any example of this being done in a WCF Workflow Service Application, just a  Workflow console app in which the workflow is unloaded and loaded in the Main method of the program class using

```
WorkflowApplication app = new WorkflowApplication(new Workflow1());
```

.

*Does anyone know if it is possible to pause and resume a Workflow Flowchart using some inbuilt IIS or AppFabric functionality?*

I am still quite new to WF and AppFabric so if I am missing something obvious I do apologise.

Many thanks

David